# Facebook API Get Post Share Count

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am trying to get the post share count using the PHP Facebook API (php-sdk-v4).

Right now I can get most of the information that I want, but it looks like the share count is in a different format.

Here's a basic example of my code.

```
$request = $this->fb->get(
    "/$id/posts?fields=id,message,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)&limit=10"
);
$posts = $request->getGraphEdge();
```

For the returned **$posts** I can loop through and retrieve the info that I want for most of the fields using this code:

```
$id = $post->getField( 'id' );
$message = $post->getField( 'message' );
```

**Likes** and **Comments** are retrieved a little different, but I was able to get it using this:

```
$likes = $post->getField( 'likes' )->getTotalCount();
$comments = $post->getField( 'comments' )->getTotalCount();
```

The problem that I am running into is that the **shares** count is returned as a  "GraphNode" Object and I get an error when I try to use getTotalCount. The object **$post->getField( 'shares' )** looks like this:

```
[shares] => Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [count] => 1
    )

)
```

I can not figure out the proper way to retrieve this variable, which in this case would be **1**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `$post->getField( 'shares' )->getField( 'count' )` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, this produced an error. **Fatal error: Call to a member function getField() on a non-object**

Comment: That can’t be, not if the debug output you have shown is genuine – it clearly _is_ an object if type `Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode`.

Comment: I agree. That's why this is frustrating.

Comment: GraphNode supports simple array access as well, so try `$shares=$post->getField('shares'); var_dump($shares['count']);`

Comment: That produces: `object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode)[101]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      'count' => int 1`

Comment: Well then try to convert that GraphNode to an array (go look up the method name in the docs, it is toArray or something like that.)

Comment: `$post->getField( 'shares' )` always says it produces an object, but when I try to add anything to the end such as `->getTotalCount()` or `->getMetaData()` or `->getField( 'count' )` it gives an error saying that its a non-object. I don't understand why I can't get access to this data. hmmm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118629/discussion-between-josh-and-cbroe).

Comment: Does it make a difference, if you store it into a variable first, instead of chaining method calls?

Comment: I found an out of the way solution. If I use `$data = $post->uncastItems()` I get an array of all the data I requested for that post. This let's me access the share count using `$data['shares']['count']` It will work for now, but it doesn't seem like the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, I think it's "proper". it's important to check if `$graphNode->getField('shares')` is not null before asking for `->getField('count')`.

```
$request = $fb->get('/' . $id . '/posts?fields=id,message,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)&limit=10');
foreach ($request->getGraphEdge() as $graphNode) {
    // Sometimes "getField" function can return a null value
    if ($graphNode->getField('shares')) {
        $numberShares = $graphNode->getField('shares')->getField('count');
    }
}
```